# Home workouts that could grow bigger arms

Tags: push-ups, upper-body-workout, biceps, arms

I need suggestions for good home workouts that could grow bigger arms/biceps/forearms 
I only know of push-ups. I am not sure if they are enough to make your arms bigger
I am looking for something without equipments

Comment: What is your experience in training?

Comment: What do you consider equipment? Do you have a pull up bar or really 0 equipment?

Comment: I'd highly suggest spending $50 on a starter resistance/thereband band set, as you can do just about every exercise with them and add resistance up to 100 lbs, in which case you can buy more bands or add more reps. If you're serious then you can buy dumbbell handles where you put the weight plates on yourself, so you only have to buy so many weights rather than an entire dumbbell set

Comment: I have used gym equipments for 1 year. But since it's lockdown I want to do everything at home and do exercise properly. Yes I do have pull up bar and dumbells too. But the thing is right now I am stuck at a relative place due to lockdown. So I am kind of out of luck. I only have yoga mat. But yes I could probably hang on gates for pullups. Not comfortable but doable. I have to become creative for it.

Answer (score 4):

> I need suggestions for good home workouts that could grow bigger arms/biceps/forearms
> I only know of push-ups.

A simple beginner routine could consist of

- **push-ups** targeting the triceps, pecs, and anterior deltoid.
- **pull-ups** targeting the lats, traps, posteriod deltoid, biceps, and teres major.
- **squats** targeting the glutes, quads, hamstrings, adductor, hip flexors, and calves.

I realize that you are only asking about growing your arms, so why did I include squats?

[Research shows](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/21327794/) that working your legs actually boosts your testosterone. The increase in testosterone actually boosted the participants bicep curls. This means that if you skip leg day, you are also missing out on arm gains.

Also, I feel that I must add this. **Without proper diet and sleep, exercise means very little.**

Comment: And what's your suggestion for these body weight exercise like push-ups/pull-ups and squats. I mean is there a limit to what they should be done in a day? Or since they are body weight could one do it for longer periods of time in a day without risking injury. Which certainly is the case when you use body weight equipments

Comment: As nowdays I have free time. So I was thinking of utilizing it well. And thinking of doing 30 mins morning and 30-45 mins evening intermediate level exercises at home. Not sure if that's a good idea. Although I have heard people not to do that with gym. But could one do it at home

Comment: There is a limit on everything. Body weight workouts tend to lead to more tendonitis than weight training simply because people don't listen to their bodies. If you find your joints feeling stressed or in pain all the time, dial it back a bit. Depending on how hard you work out each time, it might be too much, or not enough if the intensity is lacking. This really depends on how fit you are and how hard you are working. The key is to listen to how you feel. You want to work out hard enough for gains, and give yourself sufficient rest so you don't overwork yourself.

Comment: Thanks that was helpful. In general apart from those three do you suggest any other workout.

Comment: You can look into calisthenics in general. You can get quite strong with bodyweight moves as you move into harder movements. Likely the most informative youtuber for calisthenics is [CalisthenicMovement](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCZIIRX8rkNjVpP-oLMHpeDw). Perhaps take a look at his channel, he has solid information and doesn't promise instant results like many fitness channels do.

Answer (score 0):

Completely agree with Eric Warburton's answer above: Squats, Push ups, and pull ups should be your basis for training without equipment. When it comes to fitness I'd say the saying

> "All roads lead to Rome"

is accurate. However, some are more effective than others. There is a plethora of options for you in the calisthenics area for training. I would recommend the youtube channel FitnessFAQs, a great bodyweight fitness youtube channel. Also, you should invest in a doorway pull up bar (around $20) it'll be a game changer.
Since you are training bodyweight and I presume you currently do not own a pull up bar here would be my suggestion for a training regime. Since you have no weights you will be training until failure with bodyweight movements aiming to increase reps. You have mainly two options for training split, you can either:

1. Train your full body all in one workout, multiple times a week. so you would do squats, push ups, and pull ups all in one workout with rest days between the workouts.
   Monday: workout.  Tuesday: rest day.  Wednesday: workout. and so on
2. You can isolate a days workout to a certain group of muscles. the most common and probably the most effective is the push pull legs split. where you train your push muscles (chest, triceps) on one day, your pull muscles (back, biceps) on another and legs on the third.
   Monday: Push Tuesday: Pull Wednesday Legs and so on

How you train these I would suggest viewing some of FitnessFAQs videos on workouts.